# Form_Current in SubForm fires before other SubForm(s) update

Tags: vba, ms-access

Scenario: Unbound master form with two subforms, both bound to tables that share the same ID. The subforms are tied together via an unbound field `txtID=[SubForm1]![ID]` on MasterForm and SubForm2 `Link Master Fields = txtID` & `Link Child Fields = ID`, as describes [here](https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp). SubForm1 has record navigaion. SubForm2 always shows the record with the same ID as the record in SubForm1 (if any) = works as intended.

I implemented a routine to compare the records (which partially have the same data fields - unfortunately I've to work with these two data sources), highlighting differences - works as intended.

**Problem**: calling this comparison from `Form_Current()` in SubForm1 revealed unexpected behaviour: **the event fires and the comparison is done *before* SubForm2 is updated** (=> the comparison goes wrong).

Pausing code execution for some seconds before calling the comprison routine - I tested that out of curiosity - shows that sometimes the update of SubForm2 finishes before code execution continues, and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: I call the code from SubForm2 `Current` event.

Another possibility would be to switch over to a *bound* master form displaying the data that is displayed in my SubForm1, with the other data in a SubForm as usual - as far as I tried, this SubForm always has already updated before the code called from the master form's `Current` event executes.